# Copying Conditional Formatting without adding to the data set

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an inventory and ordering management Sheet where I use color coding via Sheets Conditional Formatting to make some cells quickly visible as having outstanding orders.  In my particular case, I am using conditional formatting based on a neighboring cell.

The sheet I built utilizes several columns for ordering cycles with our suppliers.  When I am ready to move on to the next ordering cycle, I copy and paste a set of columns to create the new cycle.

The problem that I encounter is this: the new column's Conditional Formatting gets added to the old, both in terms of adding a new column to format, but also referencing the cell from which the copied columns use to decide whether to format.

[Original Order Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyDK0.png)

In this second image, I have pasted a new order block from Columns AD-AL to Columns AM -AU.

[Pasted Order Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvEiI.png)

There are two things that I am trying to solve:

- I would expect the custom formula to update to =$AR5<>"", but it holds on to the Original Order Block's formula, thus applying the formatting from cells that are in the Original Order Block.
- I would expect the range to update to only the new range of AQ5:AQ397, rather than add the additional range to the original order block range.

Each order block needs the conditional formatting to be independent from the one which it was copied.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just remove the "$" from your custom formula and it will move just fine

Your ranges are going to be together as you shown, but will look at the cell at its right

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin.  That did it.  As I was sorting through various solutions, I tried what you suggested and just saw the data range expanding and the referenced cell for the custom formula staying the same and overlooked that it would actually work with those.    It is working now.  Muchas gracias!